# Software version numbering with GIT

Tags: git, versioning, git-tag

**Overview**: I want to set automatic (or at least semi-auto) software version numbering in Git.

I want to set some starting version number (like v1.0) to my project. I know, there is `tag` for this reason. Googled it and found bunch of materials. For example:

[git - the simple guide](http://rogerdudler.github.com/git-guide/) blog says:

> You can create a new tag named 1.0.0 by executing `git tag 1.0.0 1b2e1d63ff` the `1b2e1d63ff` stands for the first 10 characters of the commit id you want to reference with your tag.

[Kudelabs](http://www.kudelabs.com/2011/12/22/tags-in-git-for-sane-version-numbers) says:

```
$ git tag -a 'milestone1' -m 'starting work for milestone 1, due in 2 weeks'
$ git push --tags
```

I'm really confused. What is difference between first and second method: `git tag` and `git tag -a`. Can't figure out which to use for this purpose.

How can I set version number in bare remote repo, to which I made 5-6 commits and pushes?

Answer (score 1):

`git describe` by default uses annotated tags. So, to follow the convention create them annotated (`-a`) as Kudelabs says.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't have automatic version numbering. You'd have to write your own scripts to do that using `git tag`.

If you provide more information about how you want your version numbers to be assigned, we might be able to help further.

Comment: I don't want to think some algorithm for this or reinvent the wheel. Just want to use some patternt that developers usually use

Comment: @revocoderrevocorp the pattern is that people just use git tag directly when they are ready for a new version. Anything else (automated, semi-automated) is up to the project and is not standardized.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git tag -a -m
```

is called annotated tag. The value (in "") after the `-a` is used as the tag name, while the value after the `-m` is used as a tag description message.

**Use Tags not a million times (as for buildnumbers)**
Increment only time over time.

**Automatic tagging workflow:**
Depending on your IDE you are using, there is normally an option to run shell commands with each build or ftp-upload or whatever. Use that shell script to run each time you're building your project to check if a new version exists (perhaps defined in your IDE). If so you can run the git command from shell and add a tag.

Here is how to do it in Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091310/heres-how-to-auto-increment-the-build-number-in-xcode
Other IDEs maybe handle that thing similarly